# Django template extends wrong template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have multiple apps in my project:

- app1/

  - templates/

    - base.html
    - some_template.html
- app2/

  - templates/

    - base.html
    - overview/

      - index.html

app2/templates/overview.index.html has this code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

So it should extend `app2/templates/base.html`

But in fact it extends `app1/templates/base.html`! Why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app template loader returns the first template that matches, it doesn't know that you are rendering a template 'inside' a specific app.

The [Django docs recommend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something) that you put your app's templates in `myapp/templates/myapp`, not `myapp/templates/`. This prevents the templates from clashing.

> Now we might be able to get away with putting our templates directly in `polls/templates` (rather than creating another polls subdirectory), but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will choose the first template it finds whose name matches, and if you had a template with the same name in a different application, Django would be unable to distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the right one, and the easiest way to ensure this is by namespacing them. That is, by putting those templates inside another directory named for the application itself.

So in your case, you would change the structure to

- app1/

  - templates/

    - app1/

      - base.html
      - some_template.html
- app2/

  - templates/

    - app2/

      - base.html
      - overview/

        - index.html

You would then have to update the template name in your view, e.g.

```
return render(request, 'app2/some_template.html', {})
```

and in your template

```
{% extends 'app2/base.html' %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why? Because that's how discovering of django templates works.

Django will search for templates in each app's templates dir (in order that apps are presented in `INSTALLED_APPS`) and in global templates dirs. First found template will be served. This allows one app to use templates from other. It also allows to change templates for one app by another. Without that there wouldn't be easy way to style your admin panel by your own.

How to fix it? Create subdirectory in templates in each of your apps and keep here app-specific templates. Of course you will have to access them by entering path like:

```
{% extends 'app2/base.html' %}
```